# Script is not being called via $.ajax / PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery

I created a php file system with create folder, update, upload files, and delete files. Everything works fine except for Upload files. when the upload button is clicked , it open the upload file form but when submitted 'upload.php' script is not called. I cant figure out the reason.

*here is the entire code*

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>PHP Filesystem with Ajax JQuery</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <br /><br />
    <div class="container">
        <h2 align="center">PHP Filesystem with Ajax JQuery</a></h2>
        <br />
        <div align="right">
            <button type="button" name="create_folder" id="create_folder" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="table-responsive" id="folder_table">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

<div id="folderModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span id="change_title">Create Folder</span></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Enter Folder Name
                    <input type="text" name="folder_name" id="folder_name" class="form-control" /></p>
                <br />
                <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" />
                <input type="hidden" name="old_name" id="old_name" />
                <input type="button" name="folder_button" id="folder_button" class="btn btn-info" value="Create" />

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="uploadModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Upload File</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" id="upload_form" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                    <p>Select Image
                        <input type="file" name="upload_file[]" multiple /></p>
                    <br />
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_folder_name" id="hidden_folder_name" />
                    <input type="submit" name="upload_button" class="btn btn-info" value="Upload" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="filelistModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">File List</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="file_list">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        load_folder_list();

        function load_folder_list() {
            var action = "fetch";
            $.ajax({
                url: "action.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    action: action
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#folder_table').html(data);
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).on('click', '#create_folder', function() {
            $('#action').val("create");
            $('#folder_name').val('');
            $('#folder_button').val('Create');
            $('#folderModal').modal('show');
            $('#old_name').val('');
            $('#change_title').text("Create Folder");
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#folder_button', function() {
            var folder_name = $('#folder_name').val();
            var old_name = $('#old_name').val();
            var action = $('#action').val();
            if (folder_name != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "action.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        folder_name: folder_name,
                        old_name: old_name,
                        action: action
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#folderModal').modal('hide');
                        load_folder_list();
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("Enter Folder Name");
            }
        });

        $(document).on("click", ".update", function() {
            var folder_name = $(this).data("name");
            $('#old_name').val(folder_name);
            $('#folder_name').val(folder_name);
            $('#action').val("change");
            $('#folderModal').modal("show");
            $('#folder_button').val('Update');
            $('#change_title').text("Change Folder Name");
        });

        $(document).on("click", ".delete", function() {
            var folder_name = $(this).data("name");
            var action = "delete";
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove it?")) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "action.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        folder_name: folder_name,
                        action: action
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        load_folder_list();
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.upload', function() {
            var folder_name = $(this).data("name");
            $('#hidden_folder_name').val(folder_name);
            $('#uploadModal').modal('show');
        });

        $('#upload_form').on('submit', function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "upload.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    load_folder_list();
                    alert(data);
                },
                
            });
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.view_files', function() {
            var folder_name = $(this).data("name");
            var action = "fetch_files";
            $.ajax({
                url: "action.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    action: action,
                    folder_name: folder_name
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#file_list').html(data);
                    $('#filelistModal').modal('show');
                }
            });
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.remove_file', function() {
            var path = $(this).attr("id");
            var action = "remove_file";
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this file?")) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "action.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        path: path,
                        action: action
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        $('#filelistModal').modal('hide');
                        load_folder_list();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $(document).on('blur', '.change_file_name', function() {
            var folder_name = $(this).data("folder_name");
            var old_file_name = $(this).data("file_name");
            var new_file_name = $(this).text();
            var action = "change_file_name";
            $.ajax({
                url: "action.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    folder_name: folder_name,
                    old_file_name: old_file_name,
                    new_file_name: new_file_name,
                    action: action
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
if($_FILES["upload_file"]["name"] != '')
{
    $data = explode(".", $_FILES["upload_file"]["name"]);
    $extension = $data[1];
    $allowed_extension = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif');
    if(in_array($extension, $allowed_extension)){
        $new_file_name = rand() . '.' . $extension;
        $path = $_POST["hidden_folder_name"] . '/' . $new_file_name;
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"], $path)){
            echo 'Image Uploaded';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'There is some error';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'Invalid Image File';
    }
}else{
    echo 'Please Select Image';
}
?>
```

**action.php**

```
<?php

function format_folder_size($size)
{
    if ($size >= 1073741824) {
        $size = number_format($size / 1073741824, 2) . ' GB';
    } elseif ($size >= 1048576) {
        $size = number_format($size / 1048576, 2) . ' MB';
    } elseif ($size >= 1024) {
        $size = number_format($size / 1024, 2) . ' KB';
    } elseif ($size > 1) {
        $size = $size . ' bytes';
    } elseif ($size == 1) {
        $size = $size . ' byte';
    } else {
        $size = '0 bytes';
    }
    return $size;
}

function get_folder_size($folder_name)
{
    $total_size = 0;
    $file_data = scandir($folder_name);
    foreach ($file_data as $file) {
        if ($file === '.' or $file === '..') {
            continue;
        } else {
            $path = $folder_name . '/' . $file;
            $total_size = $total_size + filesize($path);
        }
    }
    return format_folder_size($total_size);
}

if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
    if ($_POST["action"] == "fetch") {
        $folder = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');

        $output = '
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <tr>
    <th>Folder Name</th>
    <th>Total File</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Update</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
    <th>Upload File</th>
    <th>View Uploaded File</th>
   </tr>
   ';
        if (count($folder) > 0) {
            foreach ($folder as $name) {
                $output .= '
     <tr>
      <td>' . $name . '</td>
      <td>' . (count(scandir($name)) - 2) . '</td>
      <td>' . get_folder_size($name) . '</td>
      <td><button type="button" name="update" data-name="' . $name . '" class="update btn btn-warning btn-xs">Update</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" name="delete" data-name="' . $name . '" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" name="upload" data-name="' . $name . '" class="upload btn btn-info btn-xs">Upload File</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" name="view_files" data-name="' . $name . '" class="view_files btn btn-default btn-xs">View Files</button></td>
     </tr>';
            }
        } else {
            $output .= '
    <tr>
     <td colspan="6">No Folder Found</td>
    </tr>
   ';
        }
        $output .= '</table>';
        echo $output;
    }

    if ($_POST["action"] == "create") {
        if (!file_exists($_POST["folder_name"])) {
            mkdir($_POST["folder_name"], 0777, true);
            echo 'Folder Created';
        } else {
            echo 'Folder Already Created';
        }
    }
    if ($_POST["action"] == "change") {
        if (!file_exists($_POST["folder_name"])) {
            rename($_POST["old_name"], $_POST["folder_name"]);
            echo 'Folder Name Change';
        } else {
            echo 'Folder Already Created';
        }
    }

    if ($_POST["action"] == "delete") {
        $files = scandir($_POST["folder_name"]);
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if ($file === '.' or $file === '..') {
                continue;
            } else {
                unlink($_POST["folder_name"] . '/' . $file);
            }
        }
        if (rmdir($_POST["folder_name"])) {
            echo 'Folder Deleted';
        }
    }

    if ($_POST["action"] == "fetch_files") {
        $file_data = scandir($_POST["folder_name"]);
        $output = '
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <tr>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>File Name</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
   </tr>
  ';

        foreach ($file_data as $file) {
            if ($file === '.' or $file === '..') {
                continue;
            } else {
                $path = $_POST["folder_name"] . '/' . $file;
                $output .= '
    <tr>
     <td><img src="' . $path . '" class="img-thumbnail" height="50" width="50" /></td>
     <td contenteditable="true" data-folder_name="' . $_POST["folder_name"] . '"  data-file_name = "' . $file . '" class="change_file_name">' . $file . '</td>
     <td><button name="remove_file" class="remove_file btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="' . $path . '">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
    ';
            }
        }
        $output .= '</table>';
        echo $output;
    }

    if ($_POST["action"] == "remove_file") {
        if (file_exists($_POST["path"])) {
            unlink($_POST["path"]);
            echo 'File Deleted';
        }
    }

    if ($_POST["action"] == "change_file_name") {
        $old_name = $_POST["folder_name"] . '/' . $_POST["old_file_name"];
        $new_name = $_POST["folder_name"] . '/' . $_POST["new_file_name"];
        if (rename($old_name, $new_name)) {
            echo 'File name change successfully';
        } else {
            echo 'There is an error';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Its is working fine. Upload button is working and calling upload.php - I can not reproduce this issue. Is your modal closing right after you click on upload button ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping . yes. My model closes right after i click the upload button.

Comment: ......And you can not see the ajax (upload.php) being called in your network console ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes. i cant see upload.php being called in network console.! site reloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method in your upload function to make sure that site is not `reloading` and the `ajax` is getting `called` when you click on `upload` button in your `modal`.

**Change your `upload_form` function to this:** (tested this code and it works)

```
$(document).on('click', '.upload', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault() //use prevent default
   var folder_name = $(this).data("name");
    $('#hidden_folder_name').val(folder_name);
    $('#uploadModal').modal('show');
});

$('#upload_form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault() //use prevent default
  //Ajax
  $.ajax({
    url: "upload.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
      load_folder_list();
      alert(data);
    },
  });
});
```

**Upload.php file code**

You have some issues in your `upload.php`  file as well. You will be getting errors since you are using multiple file upload and sending the data as `Array` via ajax.

So, you need to `foreach` in your PHP file as well to get all `files` you are have sent over to be `uploaded` in your folder.

Replace your `upload.php` code to this: (tested and all working)

```
<?php
if($_FILES["upload_file"]["name"] != '') {
    foreach ($_FILES["upload_file"]["name"] as $key => $file) { //use foreach
        $data = explode(".", $file);
        $extension = $data[1];
        $allowed_extension = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif');
        if(in_array($extension, $allowed_extension)){
            $new_file_name = rand() . '.' . $extension;
            $path = $_POST["hidden_folder_name"] . '/' . $new_file_name;     
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"][$key], $path)){ //use key for each file to be moved
                echo 'Image Uploaded';
            }
            else {
                echo 'There is some error';
            }
        }else{
            echo 'Invalid Image File';
        }
    }
}else{
    echo 'Please Select Image';
}
?>
```

Comment: @Shishere Yes there are some issues in your PHP file. Thats has nothing to do with the actual question. but i am happy to help - I will fix it for you. I will update my answer soon with working upload.php file.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I hv been trying to find the solution for a whole night . Your's were a great help.

Comment: i am asking another doubt which has nothing to do with the original question. i am getting same error i mentioned above. shows 'Invalid image file' but files are uploaded too.

Comment: @Shishere Are you sure the files are uploading are the correct format ? I do not have this error as long as i am upload the correct files with format ending in `'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif'`

Comment: @Shishere That is weird. I do not have any error [Link](https://ibb.co/d45LS61) - Just copy the exact code i have provided above. The errors you have shown come from line 4 which is foreach loop. Copy the exact code i have provided. I do not see any issue at all.